# Data padrão para vencimento - PHP

Tags: php, data

Pesquisei por esta questão aqui no portal e, apesar de constar perguntas parecidas, não achei nada no sentido que preciso. No google também não encontrei nada que auxilie exatamente em meu problema.

Baseando-se na data da primeira parcela, preciso calcular automaticamente a data de vencimento de n parcelas, sendo estas com o dia fixo para todas elas.

Exemplo:

Primeira parcela: 25/09/2016

Ao incrementar 30 dias a esta data, o dia de vencimento para cada mês poderá variar, de acordo com o tamanho do mês. Além disso, pode acontecer o caso de algum mês ser "pulado", como no mês de fevereiro.

Daí então, preciso que ele realize algo no sentido abaixo:

Primeira parcela: 30/01/2016

A segunda parcela deverá ser: 29/2/2016
A terceira parcela deverá ser: 30/03/2016
A quarta parcela deverá ser: 30/04/2016
E assim sucessivamente.

O que vocês me dizem? Podem me auxiliar nessa questão?
Qualquer sugestão é bem vinda.

Abçs

Answer (score 3):

Seria uma lógica verificando sempre a data gerada é válida:

```
<?php

function parcelas($data, $numero)
{
    $parc = array();
    $parc[] = $data;
    list($dia, $mes, $ano) = explode("/", $data);
    for($i = 1; $i < $numero;$i++)
    {
        $mes++;
        if ((int)$mes == 13)
        {
            $ano++;
            $mes = 1;
        }
        $tira = $dia;
        while (!checkdate($mes, $tira, $ano))
        {
            $tira--;
        }
        $parc[] = sprintf("%02d/%02d/%s", $tira, $mes, $ano);
    }
    return $parc;
}


$data = "29/01/2015";

var_dump(parcelas($data, 13));
```

[***Exemplo***](http://ideone.com/Q7Tmbg)

Comment: Olá Virgilio. Era exatamente isso que eu precisava! Muito obrigado.